# library wireshark in ruby

Tags: ruby, wireshark-dissector

I'm doing my project of 4th year of university and the theme of this project is to realize a network analyser with web interface close to what wireshark proposes. So its necessary to mapper the wireshark library in the ruby language,
that will allow me after to dissector the packets captured.

I have been looking for some manual or documentation about the library on the net but no success.
Afetr all i decided to join the developpers mailing list to post the question and learn about development of wireshark library.
Is there any manul or documentation , as every programming libarary and any ideas are welecome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across the [ffi-pcap](http://github.com/sophsec/ffi-pcap) library that may help you along.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is this program will allow me to make the capture of packets and to dissect later ?. I had also seen http://github.com/ffi/ffi is it the same ?

Comment: ffi-pcap seems to only capture packets.  I did a little search & came across this wrapper to pcap that may be more what you are looking for (note: looks a bit old, link to svn repo is at the bottom): http://apocryph.org/2007/11/25/major_improvements_ruby_wireshark_wrapper/